# Почему таймер выполняется раньше функции? (Python)

Tags: python, многопоточность, время

Пишу программу для распознавания речи на Python, однако при использовании time.sleep сначала выполняется таймер, а затем загружается функция, а нужно наоборот, Открыть поток, запустить таймер, по истечении времени прервать функцию и поток

```
def com():
    Thread(target=recognizer.command).start()
    time.sleep(5)
    return
```

Comment: а почему вы решили, что сначала таймер выполняется?

Comment: В функции command (вызывается в потоке), выводится строка о начале записи, проблема точно не в модуле threading, т.к. без таймера все выводиться, а при использовании таймера строка выводиться ровно через выставленное время например, 5 секунд

Comment: Не очень понятно, но вывод на печать буферизируется и т.д. Нельзя на нем строить понимание о том, что сначала, а что потом происходит. Т.е. поток у вас, скорее, стартует вовремя, потом запускается таймер, а вот печать задерживается.